# jQuery animating object to look like its floating in water

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

So I'm fairly new to jQuery and I'm trying to have a continuos animation of an iceberg floating in water.

**This is the iceberg on water..**

[image]

And I want it to kinda rotate and bob, this is my current code for a looping animation.. Just need some help getting it to do what i want ha!

```
function iceburg() {
    jQuery('.iceburg').css({bottom:0});
    jQuery('.iceburg').animate ({
        bottom: '10px'
    }, 200, function() {
        jQuery('.iceburg').animate ({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 200);
    });
}
iceburg();
```

I cant figure out what im doing wrong and how to rotate it? Can anyone help please?

Comment: Agree with @TCHdvlp on the optimisation comment. Each time you use `jQuery('.iceburg')`, jQuery, traverses the DOM to find every element with that class. It's better to create a variable with that jQuery object, and re-use that. You'll get better performance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var ice = $('.iceburg');

function anim() {
    setInterval(function(){
        ice.animate({
            top:'+=20'},
          { 
            duration:1000,
            step:function()
                  { ice.css('-webkit-transform','rotate(-0.5deg)');}
                });

       ice.animate({
              top:'-=20'},
             { 
               duration:1000,
               step:function()
                  { ice.css('-webkit-transform','rotate(0.5deg)');}
                });
         });
   }

   anim();
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/dkFqQ/

Comment: Very helpful! Exactly what i was looking for! Sadly you cant animate 'rotate' smoothly, right?

Comment: @LeviCole you can try some easing library, it can help :)

Answer (score 0):

You must set a loop if you want your effect to... loop. Use `setInterval`

http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/kj6tk/1/

Also, Use `$(this)` in your callback instead of `jQuery('.iceburg')` a second time